# Make sure a password matches a user name using java

Tags: java, arrays, passwords, hashmap

Hello all thanks for your time. I need to write a method which will validate a user's credentials.  I have an array of strings for the usernames and an array of strings for passwords I want the user to input a username and password into a dialog box and then check whether or not that username and password match but I seem to be hitting a wall whereby even if the password and user name is valid it returns false.

```
 private static final String[] EMPLOYEE = { "Abe", "Bob", "Cud"}; // names of all employees
 private static final String[] EMPLOYEE_PSWD = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}; // passwords for the employees in same order as names
```

Above are the arrays as fields, below are the OptionPane declarations.

```
    userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a username:", "Login", QSTN);

    password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a password:", "Login", QSTN);

    verifyUser(userName,password);
```

(This is a snippet of a main method. The whole project is to create a Sales report program where an employee enters credentials then enters what he/she sold.  If you need me to put the whole thing up let me know)

This is what I have tried to use I've simply been spitting out ideas:

```
 private static void verifyUser(String userName, String password)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<EMPLOYEE.length; i++)
    {
        HashMap<String,String> login = new HashMap<String, String>();
        login.put(EMPLOYEE[i],EMPLOYEE_PSWD[i]);            
        if(!login.get(userName).equals(EMPLOYEE_PSWD[i]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid password or username", "Error", INFO);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


}
```

If you guys need anything else just let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: you are comparing input user name with a stored password. Is that a requirement?

Comment: Yes its a very bare-bones excersize not really meant to be safe or secure the names and passwords where predecided and we have to use those.  Of course the inputted user needs to be one of the Employees if not it should bring up a dialog saying "error invalid user"  as far as that i'm fine I just can't get it to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
private static void verifyUser(String userName, String password) {
    //null check and all

    Map<String, String> login = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEE.length; i++) {
        login.put(EMPLOYEE[i], EMPLOYEE_PSWD[i]);
    }
    if (login != null && login.size() > 0 && password.equals(login.get(userName))) {
        System.out.println("Valid username and password");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid password or username");
    }
}
```

**Update:** Changed reference from HashMap to interface Map.

Comment: Its better to use java collection.. It is more readable many times.

Comment: OK thanks ill go ahead and change it and keep it in mind for a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need HashMap, take it easy.

```
boolean ok = false;
for(int i = 0; i<EMPLOYEE.length; i++)
{
    ok |= EMPLOYEE[i].equals(username) && EMPLOYEE_PSWD[i].equals(password);
}
if (ok) {} // password match
else {} // wrong password
```

Comment: Oh haha thank you that's one of my biggest problems, making things more complex than they nee d to be! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 private static void verifyUser(String userName, String password)
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEE.length; i++)
     {
          if (EMPLOYEE[i].equals(userName))
          {
                if (!EMPLOYEE_PSWD[i].equals(password))
                {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid password or username", "Error", INFO);
                      System.exit(0);
                }

                // login was successful
          }
     }  
 }
```